# How to setup a reset function for a factory object?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

So here is a simple object..

```
angular.module('POSapp')
.factory('RequestedPayment', function() {

return {
    btcValue: 0,
    timeGenerated: 0,
    paid: false,
    destAddress: '',
    idrAmount: '',
    usdAmount: ''
};
});
```

I inject the above the factory object into various controllers. e.g.

```
angular.module('POSapp')
.controller('InvoiceController', function($scope, $location, $timeout, RequestedPayment, CurrencyConvert) {

$scope.reqPayment = RequestedPayment;
```

For certain conditions I need to reset the factory object back to the initial defaults. What is the cleanest way to do this?

Maybe refactor the factory so I can do something like

```
$scope.reqPayment = RequestedPayment.reset();
```

Any best practices?
Thanks.

Comment: I don't understand your question... Your factory returns on each call an resetted object. So if you want an clean object just call `$scope.reqPayment = RequestedPayment;` again.

Comment: I want to share data between controllers.. so if I change the values e.g. $scope.reqPayment.usdAmount = 5.4; then when I pass RequestedPayment into another controller and go $scope.reqPayment = RequestedPayment; I get the updated value, not the initial value. This has been helpful! The only way to reset that factory has been to refresh the page or manually re-assign the values.

Comment: @Sven that's not how factories work in Angular. The factory function runs once, and Angular internally caches its return value.

Comment: @MichalCharemza I have shown in [documentation](https://docs.angularjs.org/guide/providers#factory-recipe) and I found that the reference to the service will be cached. Not the value

Comment: @SvenSchürmann If you look at http://plnkr.co/edit/9VkSZRvAqbEnXqCSciXa?p=preview where the factory returns a random number, then you can see that it's injected into 3 different controllers, and shows the exact same value in the template. If it wasn't being cached by Angular, each would show a different number.

Comment: @MichalCharemza: Sorry... You 're right! Thanks for the advice

Answer (score 3):

Since you're using a single instance of the data itself then why not use `.service()` which actually returns a singleton. Create a function that will be instantiated as an angular service that has a `reset()` method that resets the current value of the object.

**[DEMO](http://jsfiddle.net/z94xjwku/1/)**

```
(function() {

    // original data
    var originalData = {
        btcValue: 0,
        timeGenerated: 0,
        paid: false,
        destAddress: '',
        idrAmount: '',
        usdAmount: ''
    };

    function RequestedPayment() {
        // calls the reset function defined below
        this.reset();
    }

    RequestedPayment.prototype.reset = function() {
        // angular extend deep copies enumerable properties of the `originalData` object
        // to the properties that RequestPayment has, overwriting any values that exist
        // within the `originalData` object.
        angular.extend(this, originalData);
    };

    angular.module('POSapp', [])

        .service('RequestedPayment', RequestedPayment)

        .run(function(RequestedPayment) {
            console.log(RequestedPayment.btcValue);
            RequestedPayment.btcValue = 100;
            console.log(RequestedPayment.btcValue);
            RequestedPayment.reset();
            console.log(RequestedPayment.btcValue);
        });

})();
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm having trouble getting it to run. So in my RequestedPayment.js file I have the following code: http://jsfiddle.net/magician11/wq8m8mrq/1/ But then injecting it into my controllers doesn't seem to work. At least I don't seem to have access to the object using something like console.log. I don't see any errors being displayed either.

Comment: I have [**updated the jsfiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/wq8m8mrq/2/) you have provided, I added a form and a controller that injects the service itself, and it works perfectly.